# POST something using editable dropdown

Tags: php, html

I made an editable dropdown menu :

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="position:relative;width:200px;height:25px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;">
    <select style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:200px; height:25px;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0;" onchange="document.getElementById('displayValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('idValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

        <option></option>
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text" name="displayValue" placeholder="add/select a value" id="displayValue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:183px;width:180px\9;#width:180px;height:23px; height:21px\9;#height:18px;border:1px solid #556;" onfocus="this.select()">
    <input type="hidden" name="idValue" id="idValue">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to POST the value that was added, so as to include it in drop down for the next round.

Comment: "Combo boxes" like the one you are trying to create are not well supported in HTML. I would recommend having an option for "other" in your dropdown menu and using a separate text box below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `jQuery` for easy implementation. You can wrap them in a `form` and do the `POST`ing via `jQuery Ajax` then store that value somewhere for future use then append it to the next as the new `option` item.

**POST via aJax**

```
$(function() {
    $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
        // do not reload the page
        e.preventDefault();

        // do the posting
        var newValue = $('#displayValue').val();

        $.post('http://MYURL.com/post.php', {
            new_field: newValue
        }, function(data) {
            // success callback
            $('#form > select').append('<option value="'+newValue+'">'+newValue+'</option>');
        })
    });
})
```

Basically, you post `newValue` to `http://MYURL.com/post.php` and handle that new data then the `success` callback will handle the inserting of the new value to your `select`.

*the code is not tested, let me know if it did not work*

Learn more about [jquery.post() here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and more about [jquery here](http://jquery.com/)